# Unexpected Kernel Mode Trap BSOD

Tags: bsod

since last 2 months or so I'm getting this BSOD randomly on latest updated win10 ultimate x64. Which usually occur when sometimes I try to move my mouse I guess? but i'm not sure. So the problem never reappears after a reboot though but when I fresh start my pc again some other time it randomly comes again and yet so far it never happened within a fullscreen video or game. It only says "UNEXPECTED KERNEL TRAP" is this some kind of windows update bug or hardware / drivers issue?

Thanks in advance.

Minidump : https://drive.google.com/open?id=1rB6PJ8UzTAYA4Ye4hkBbuUREeuhpAWHT

Edit 3 :

Thanks for indepth answer, well I guess the nature of BSOD didn't change as once I got the same KERNEL MODE TRAP ERROR AFTER THAT. Although these errors are somewhat rare but alamring right? My guess was the graphic drivers too but they are updated to latest. All I can try now is to remove the Catalyst / Anderline Suite and only install the driverrs simple way? and here is the smart and all other info from speccy: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1xEidyz2g-g5Zoa6Or2nzE6mIOimKotPi (snapshot) https://drive.google.com/open?id=13gjZlSwQw6Em-F9xPtvVvgKBEa2B8GOw (text file) The only issue I saw there was motherboard temperature at 110 as you can maybe read in the info. and the SFC now command says this : Windows Resource Protection found corrupt files but was unable to fix some of them.
For online repairs, details are included in the CBS log file located at
windir\Logs\CBS\CBS.log. For example C:\Windows\Logs\CBS\CBS.log. For offline
repairs, details are included in the log file provided by the /OFFLOGFILE flag. and the Dism command reports this : Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
Version: 10.0.18362.1

Image Version: 10.0.18363.752

No component store corruption detected.
The operation completed successfully.

Comment: Very complete error info. Of the 5 `.dmp` files, 2 happened in `ntfs.sys`, which may indicate disk problems. Please add to the post the SMART data of your disks and run `chkdsk` on all disks.

Comment: Tried chkdsk it fixed some errors in C now I got a IRQ not LESS or Equal BSOD here's fresh log after that: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1IFb0Y4IZin191zc8Khb9RfPfth1CMVRt

Answer (score 0):

The fact that `chkdsk` fixed some errors and this changed the nature of the crash
is very worrisome.

Please also check the SMART info of the disk
(one utility for that is [Speccy](https://www.ccleaner.com/speccy))
and post it. Also run
[sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html)
and also the DISM command at the end of this article.

If this doesn't help:

Your last crash arrives in `atikmdag.sys`.
ATIKMDag stands for **ATI** Radeon **K**ernel **M**ode **D**river Pack**ag**e,
so belongs to your display driver.

Try first to download and install the latest video card driver from the
[AMD website](https://www.amd.com/en/support).

If that doesn't help, and as `chkdsk` found errors in sensitive Windows files,
I would suggest to
[Do a Repair Install of Windows 10 with an In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html).
This will restore Windows components to a known state, but may require reinstalling
the Radeon driver.
This operation is equivalent to installing a major Windows upgrade, so is not
too dangerous, but take the usual precautions as regarding backup.

Comment: Thanks for indepth answer, well I guess the nature of BSOD didn't change as once I got the same KERNEL MODE TRAP ERROR AFTER THAT. Although these errors are somewhat rare but alamring right? My guess was the graphic drivers too but they are updated to latest. All I can try now is to remove the Catalyst / Anderline Suite and only install the driverrs simple way? and here is the smart and all other info from speccy:

Comment: Where is this info?

Comment: I updated first post as it won't allow me to post so much text as a comment?

Comment: If SFC was unable to fix the errors, I think that a Repair Install is required to bring everything to a consistent state. Follow the link in my answer.